# How to create a modal popup to login when the user is not authenticated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this view that displays a table of data:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated){
    <fieldset id="detailPrix">
        <legend>Details prix</legend>
            <div class="scrollableContainer">
            <div class="scrollingArea">
            <table class="cruises scrollable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Carburant
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Prix
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Date d'ajout
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Mettre à jour
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @for(int index =0; index<Model.carburants.Count;index++){
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayName(Model.carburants[index].data.ToString())
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayName(Model.prixCarburants[index].ToString())
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayName(Model.dateAjoutCarburants[index].ToString())
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "ModifierPrix", new {carbuId = Model.carburants[index].id, stationId= Model.station.id, Myvmsd=Model, index=index, prix=Model.prixCarburants[index]})
                            </td>
                        </tr> 
                    </tbody>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
}
else{
     // If the user didn't authenticated, I want to display the popup modal to login (in JQuery or JS). 
}
```

I want my login view into the modal popup. This is my login view :

```
<section id="loginForm">
<h2>Connexion avec un compte local.</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Formulaire de connexion.</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input id="LogIn" type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") Si vous n'avez pas de compte.
    </p>
}
</section>

<section class="social" id="socialLoginForm">
    <h2>Connexion via Les réseaux sociaux</h2>
    @Html.Action("ExternalLoginsList", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
</section>
```

It's possible to display this view into a modal popup in JQuery for example ?
Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Normally that is not the way you approach it. What you are showing us here is that the view is rendered along with a possible "login view" tucked in the `else` section. You are putting the logic in your view that is not the standard way of doing it - at least not for a "login view". A better way of doing it is to check the "authentication" on the controller and show the login view from there or redirect to a login method. Or check by ajax and show/return a different view. Lots of "better way" of doing it.

Comment: It's not possible to make this with a @Html.Action() ?

Comment: The idea is to have a 1:1 relationship between a view and a method. It's not good that a single view represents two actions. You can use `IsAuthenticated` to hide some element, for example, a "log out link" instead of a "log in link". But to show an entirely different view (in the same cshtml file) serving another purpose, it's really not a good idea. So what you can do is have a link inside the else that will trigger the modal. The modal's content is another view (another file) that can be served by another method called via ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

In the else statement I change the last `<td>`  like :

```
<td>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Se logger", "Login", "Account", null, new { @class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id = "loginDialog", data_dialog_title = "Log in"})
    </p>
</td>
```

in my _Layout I add this `<script>` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("<div></div>")
                .addClass("dialog")
                .attr("id", $(this)
                .attr("data-dialog-id"))
                .appendTo("body")
                .dialog({
                    title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                    close: function () { $(this).remove(); },
                    modal: true,
                    height: 250,
                    width: 400,
                    left: 0
                })
            .load(this.href);
        });

        $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
        });
});
</script>
```

It works perfectly now.
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below 
VIEW:

```
    <div id="login">
        <section id="loginForm">
        <h2>Connexion avec un compte local.</h2>
        @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Formulaire de connexion.</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <input id="LogIn" type="submit" value="Log in" />
            </fieldset>
            <p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register") Si vous n'avez pas de compte.
            </p>
        }
        </section>
    </div>
<input type="button" id="loginbtn" />


    <script>
   var $login=  $('#login').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: '',
                modal: true,
                width: 50,
                height: 50
            });

    // you need to write button click event to open it
    $('#loginbtn').click(function(){
    $login.dialog('open');
    });
    </script>
```

Ask if any issue.

Comment: Thanxs for your answer. But I don't put this view into the else statement because the model of the login view is not the same than the table view.