# How to change the value of Layout in JQuery ?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I created a modal popup as you will see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544471/how-to-create-a-modal-popup-to-login-when-the-user-is-not-authenticated). my problem is that I need the layout when the user connects normally but not when I display modal popup using the same login for. So I want to make something like :

```
$("@Layout").setValue(null);
```

I'd like to know if it is possible.
Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: So you want to remove layout from popup...?

Comment: Yes I want to know if it's possible

Comment: I just added a new login view without Layout and redirect to the associate controlleur. It's works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove layout from view,

Just put this above your view

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

A better approach will be using partial view inside the Pop-Up.

Comment: Yes but if I will do that, I Haven't Layout in my normal login page. I want to make that only in the popup. I will try to make it in a Partial View.